# stop movement when energy is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am creating a 4 player game using node.js, socket.io and create.js. In my game every player has energy and when player is moving energy is decreasing. I want to stop player when energy is 0 or less. But I couldn't do it.

**Server Side:**

```
socket.on('move', function(data)
                     {
                         var w = data["dir"];
                         var x = data["x"];
                         var y = data["y"];
                         var e = data["energy"];
                         console.log(e);
                                if(w == "down")
                                    y += 5;

                                if(w == "up")
                                    y -= 5;

                                if(w == "left")
                                    x -= 5;

                                if(w == "right")
                                    x += 5;

                                if(e <= 0)
                                {
                                    x+=0;
                                    y+=0;
                                }

                                socket.broadcast.emit("_movement2",data);
                                socket.emit("_movement",{ "X" : x, "Y" : n       y});
 });
```

**Client Side:**

```
switch(evt.keyCode)
            {
                case 37:    
                          energy--;
                            $("#energy").css({"width" : energy});
                        socket.emit("move", {"y" : player.playerImage.y,  "x": player.playerImage.x, "dir" : "left", "id":player_id, "energy" : energy});
                            break;
                case 38:    
                            energy--;
                            $("#energy").css({"width" : energy});
                            socket.emit("move", {"y" : player.playerImage.y, "x" : player.playerImage.x, "dir" : "up", "id":player_id, "energy" : energy});


                            break;
                case 39:     
                energy--;
                            $("#energy").css({"width" : energy});
                            socket.emit("move", {"x" : player.playerImage.x, "y" : player.playerImage.y, "dir": "right", "id":player_id , "energy" : energy});

                            break;
                case 40:    
                                energy--;
                            $("#energy").css({"width" : energy});
                socket.emit("move", {"y" : player.playerImage.y, "x" : player.playerImage.x, "dir" : "down", "id":player_id, "energy" : energy});
                break;
            }



        socket.on("_movement", function(data)
        {
            player.playerImage.x = data["X"];
            player.playerImage.y = data["Y"];
                });
```

Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statements are not correct.
You want to do something along the lines of:

```
if(energy <= 0) {
    //don't move
}
else {
    //move
}
```

Comment: I got it, but how actually stop player, so that he won't move.

Comment: If I don't write anything in **if** it will still continue moving.

Comment: have you moved the `if(w == ..)` into the else part?

Comment: if(e <= 0)
          {
           
           }
         
         else
         {
        
           if(w == "down")
            y += 5;
            
           if(w == "up")
            y -= 5;
           
           if(w == "left")
            x -= 5;
           
           if(w == "right")
            x += 5;
         }

Comment: Well you're moving somewhere else in your code then.

Comment: I just want to know how to stop x and y from changing. If you can help me I will be really grateful.